# Copy entity to other DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Our application needs an Offline-DB-functionality so we copy the needed entities to the `DbContext` of the offline database.

As the entities should have the same IDs, we need to deactivate the ID-generation.

In our model creation method we use the Fluent-API:

```
dbModelBuilder.Entity<Event>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

The problem is, that the entities will be saved with a generated ID (1 instead of 1234).

Inserting the old ID works with this attribute above the ID property:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public override int Id { get; set; }
```

How can we deactivate the ID generation for some entities without adding an attribute which would break our online application?

Comment: Surely this would be an EF `DbContext`, not a Linq2Sql `DataContext` ?

Comment: Yes we are using `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Comment: Are you trying to turn DatabaseGenerated on and off on different instances of your `DbContext`? Have you considered adding `DatabaseGeneratedOption` as part of your constructor? If however you are trying to add keys from different sources, consider using GUID ids instead...

Comment: There are two different classes inheriting from `DbContext`. One for online functionality with DatabaseGeneration on and one for offline functionality with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've managed to fix this problem.
Fluent API and Attributes work fine.

We've called

```
dbModelBuilder.Entity<Event>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

after the DBModel has been built.
Moving this code before `dbModelBuilder.Build()` solves the problem.